# Keyboard input doesn't affect camera

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying to make free camera, everything looks good, but I can't move it.

There is camera class:

http://pastebin.com/2w9Qcb9M

And main class:

http://pastebin.com/F4WU919x

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: You should include your code in your post, don't link to other sites. It's also good to show you've spent a bit of effort looking. For instance, have you tried stepping through the code once a button is pressed to see what happends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera class is updating a member variable `ViewMatrix` yet you're not using that anywhere in your code.